# Get 1 pixel RGB color in pygame

Tags: python, colors, pygame, rgb

How can i get one pixel RGB color in my 2D game? I need to compare it to red color(255,0,0), so i need it like this (R,G,B). I tried to use get_at() method like this:

```
if background.get_at(x,y) == (255,0,0):
    print("same")
else:
    print("not same")
```

But it didn't worked.

Comment: You may get a better response at [gamedev.stackoverflow.com](http://gamedev.stackoverflow.com) for your question.

Comment: What didn't work? Did you get an error, if so, give us the stack trace. Did it not compare equal? Then try `print(background.get_at(x,y))`. We need more information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Pygame docs: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_at
You need to do:

```
background.get_at((2,2))
```

This is passing a single argument to the function, in this case the argument is the tuple `(2,2)`

Also, if you want the colour in the form (255,0,0) then you need to call `tuple(background.get_at((2,2)))` (assuming you're using pygame version > 1.9.0).